# SQL query for fetch data from multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have the requirement to traverse three different tables of Oracle database and fetch data.

I will pass countyId to get all zipCodes from ZIP table. Based on the number of zipCodes retrieved from ZIP table, I will have pass each zip code to verify it in another table. Based on this zipCode the ACTIVITY table will return the rows of that zipCode.

How could I write the SQL query to achieve this. I heard virtual table creation concept is there but I am non-knowledgeable on that.

Please provide me high level view, How could I proceed...?

I tried the below query, but no results are retrieved - 0 rows

```
select T_ZIP5.zip,
  T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY.DTV_eligible,
  T_USER_ACTIVITY.cuid,
  T_USER_ACTIVITY.actvty_date 
from T_ZIP5
join T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY
  on T_ZIP5.FIPS_CNTY=T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY.CNTY_FIPS
join T_USER_ACTIVITY
  on T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY.zip_code=T_USER_ACTIVITY.zip
where T_ZIP5.FIPS_CNTY='53033'
```

Table Structures:

```
desc t_zip5

----------------- -------- ------------ 
ZIP               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)  
FIPS_CNTY                  VARCHAR2(5)  
CITY_NAME         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
STATE             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)  
RATE_CENTER_NAME           VARCHAR2(10) 
RATE_CENTER_STATE          VARCHAR2(2)

desc T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY

------------- -------- ------------ 
CNTY_FIPS     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)  
ZIP_CODE      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)  
DTV_ELIGIBLE           CHAR(1)      
USER_MODIFIED          VARCHAR2(10) 
CREATED_DATE           DATE         
MODIFIED_DATE          DATE

desc T_USER_ACTIVITY

----------- ---- ------------- 
ACTVTY_DATE      DATE          
ACTVTY_NAME      VARCHAR2(20)  
ACTVTY_DSCR      VARCHAR2(200) 
CUID             VARCHAR2(10)  
ZIP              VARCHAR2(5)
```

53033 is countyCode

The Zip for county is present in T_USER_ACTIVITY table. But there are multiple zip entries in T_ZIP5 table for the given county 53033.

Comment: Check out SELECT and JOIN. (Who said virtual table?)

Comment: What are your table structures, and can you show some sample data? Is 53033 a county code, or a zip code? Will there always be activity data, and what should happen if there isn't?

Comment: Alex Poole : 53033 is countycode. I have added the table structures too. Please help me on this issue

Comment: updated the question with Tables structure

Comment: You haven't shown sample data though, or said whether there is activity for that county code's ZIPs. Without the data we can't tell why you get no rows back, but one of the join conditions isn't being met.

Comment: Alex Poole : Yes, there is activity for that county code's Zip. Could you please tell what join condition I have missed out..

Comment: Not a missing join condition, but data that doesn't meet one of the conditions. Either there is no T_ZIP5 row for that county code; or not T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY row for that county code; or no T_USER_ACTIVITY row for the ZIPs associated with that code. Without the data we can't tell which. (Just a thought, but do you have any uncommitted data maybe? If you inserted the data you're expecting n one session and are querying in a different one?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join query for this.
Suppose you have three table
1. country (country_id)
2. zip (zip_id,country_id,zipcode)
3. test (test_id,zipcode);

So query like

```
SELECT zip.zipcode
  FROM country
    JOIN zip on zip.country_id = country.country_id
    JOIN test on test_id.zipcode = zip.test_id
  Where country.country_id = 10
```

Here you can use left,right join depend on your record need and you zipcode will be one entry other wise you get result as multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

This query resolved the issue..

```
 select unique T_ZIP5.zip,T_ZIP5.FIPS_CNTY,T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY.DTV_eligible,
T_USER_ACTIVITY.cuid,T_USER_ACTIVITY.actvty_date ,T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY.zip_code from T_ZIP5,T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY,T_USER_ACTIVITY where T_ZIP5.FIPS_CNTY='53033'and T_ZIP5.FIPS_CNTY=T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY.CNTY_FIPS and T_ZIP5.zip=T_USER_ACTIVITY.zip (+)
```

Comment: So there *isn't* activity data. I'd suggest you use the ANSI JOIN notation instead of Oracle's old-style joins; it's clearer, especially for outer joins.